# Tensorflow GPU - Slow Training - Lot of time spent in QueueDequeueManyV2

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow training on GPU enabled device. Below is the image of the profiler output. Training is running very slow. Based on below image, majority of the time is spent in IO - **QueueDequeueManyV2**.

How can I speed up the training?

[image]

Comment: Can you please put the image inline with the text instead of linking to it.

Comment: Its not letting me add image. Maybe because I am new user.